# The 'inscribed-circumscribed' 6 point circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles, conjectures

Here is a construction I came upon recently:

*A'B'C'* is the [contact](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContactTriangle.html) triangle. *X(*1*)* is the Incenter. *A'',B'',C''* are the midpoints of the sides of the contact triangle. A''',B''',C''' are the midpoints of the segments *AX(1), BX(1), CX(1)*. Then quadrilaterals *A''A'''C''C''', B''B'''C''C''', A''A'''B''B'''* are cyclic. Let *Ob, Oa, Oc* be the circumcenters of these 3 quadrilaterals. Finally by drawing circles with centers at Oa, Ob, Oc and passing through the incenter we get the '**[inscribed-circumscribed' six point circle](https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/zuvuyphy)** with its center at the midpoint of X(1) and X(3) - **the point X(1385)** in the ETC:

[image: The inscribed-circumscribed circle]

There is an even easier way to get a smaller concentric six point circle:
circumcircles of the quadrilaterals  *A''A'''C''C''', B''B'''C''C''', A''A'''B''B'''* cut the sides of the triangle *ABC* at six concyclic points.

The mere fact that the point  X(1385) is already described in the ETC supposedly makes the construction not particularly inspiring for a geometer.  However as this '*X(1385)-circle*' has never been previously mentioned (?) in the literature, there might still be a chance that it has some 'nice' properties of its own.

- Specifically I am interested whether any Kimberling center belongs to this 'inscribed-circumscribed' circle?  Or, alternatively, does its [central function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralCircle.html) correspond to any known center?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some symbol-bashing in *Mathematica*, here are [barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) of key points:

$$\begin{align}
A' &=  (0 : a + b - c : a - b + c) \\[0.75em]
A'' := \tfrac12(B'+C') &= 
\left(a +\frac{(a-b+c)(a+b-c)}{-a+b+c} : b : c\right) \\[0.75em]
A''' &=  (2 a + b + c :  b :  c ) \\[0.75em]
O_A &= (2 a^3 : a^3 - b^3 + c^3 + a^2 b - a^2 c - 3 a b^2 - a c^2 - b^2 c  + b c^2 - 4 a b c \\
&\phantom{(2 a^3\;}\quad : a^3  + b^3  - c^3 - a^2 b + a^2 c - a b^2 - 3 a c^2 + b^2 c  - 
  b c^2 - 4 a b c)
\end{align}$$
The coordinates of the points where, say, $\bigcirc O_A$ (the one passing through incenter $X_1$) meets the side-lines of the circle are a little messy, so I'll omit them. Nevertheless, the six prescribed points are indeed cyclic, and the equation of their common circle has this barycentric form (in $u:v:w$ coordinates):
$$\begin{align}
0 &= u^2 b c (-a + b + c) \cos A + v^2 c a (a - b + c) \cos B + w^2 a b (a + b - c) \cos C \\[0.75em]
 &\quad+ v w (-a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 2 a^2 b - 2 a^2 c - b^2 c - b c^2) \\[0.75em]
 &\quad+ w u (-b^3 + c^3 + a^3 - 2 b^2 c - 2 b^2 a - c^2 a - c a^2) \\[0.75em]
 &\quad+ u v (-c^3 + a^3 + b^3 - 2 c^2 a - 2 c^2 b - a^2 b - a b^2)
\end{align}$$

Converting to trilinear form (in $\alpha:\beta:\gamma$ coordinates), the equation can be manipulated into this:
$$(\lambda \alpha + \mu\beta+\nu\gamma)(a\alpha+b\beta+c\gamma)+\kappa(a\beta\gamma+b\gamma\alpha+c\alpha\beta)=0$$
where
$$\begin{align}
\lambda &:= (-a + b + c)\cos A \\
\mu &:= (\phantom{-}a-b+c)\cos B\\
\nu &:= (\phantom{-}a+b-c)\cos C\\
\kappa &:= -2(a+b+c)
\end{align}$$

As $\lambda:\mu:\nu$ are the trilinear coordinates for Kimberling center [$X(219)$](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html#X219) ("[$X(8)$](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html#X8)-Ceva Conjugate of [$X(55)$](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html#X55)"), the circle is the [Central Circle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralCircle.html) of that point. This answers the "alternatively" aspect of OP's question.

I don't know what Kimberling centers may lie on the circle. I don't even know how one would go about searching for them. Someone with more fluency in triangle-center lore may have some insights.

---

Incidentally, for the $\bigcirc O_A$ passing through $B''$, $B'''$, $C''$, $C'''$, etc, the corresponding six-point circle has trilinear form
$$(\lambda'\alpha+\mu'\beta+\nu'\gamma)(a\alpha+b\beta+c\gamma)+\kappa'(a\beta\gamma+b\gamma\alpha+c\alpha\beta)=0$$
where
$$\begin{align}
\lambda' &:= a (-a + b + c)^2 \\
\mu' &:= b (\phantom{-}a - b + c)^2 \\
\nu' &:= c (\phantom{-}a + b - c)^2 \\
\kappa' &:= -8 a b c
\end{align}$$
This circle is therefore the Central Circle of Kimberling's [$X(220)$](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html#X220) ("[$X(9)$](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html#X9)-Ceva conjugate of [$X(55)$](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html#X55)").

I have not investigated whether there is a general connection between OP's construction, Ceva-conjugates, and/or $X(55)$.

Comment: terrific!  I missed the deadline for awarding this bounty. I believe it was stated somewhere in the rules that the earliest approved answer gets it automatically and it is clearly yours.